# É possível usar o DataTables sem o jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, typescript, jquery-datatables, datatable

Estou fazendo um projeto que vou precisar colocar uma tabela e vou precisar colocar alguns filtros, os quais o DataTables já vem com alguns. Então estava olhando como faz para poder usar o DataTables no meu código e notei que ele só me da a opção de usar juntamente com o jQuery. Eu não estou e nem pretendo usar o jQuery no meu código. Estou usando o TypeScript, mas sem o jQuery.

Enfim, teria alguma maneira de eu conseguir usar o DataTables sem utilizar o jQuery?

Comment: Parece que não é possível, na própria [documentação](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#Requirements) informa que a única dependência é justamente o `jQuery`. Mas você pode tentar [esta alternativa](https://www.beyondjava.net/how-to-use-a-javascript-datatable-in-an-angular-application) Se seu projeto não estiver usando SSR acredito que vá de boa.

Comment: Me parece uma boa alternativa, se eu estivesse usando o Angular. Meu projeto é .NET Core Razor @Vinicius.Silva